# Redirect/Rewrite requests from IIS7 to Nginx (2 different servers)

Tags: nginx, iis, redirect, rewrite

**Context:**

We've a Microsoft Server 2019 with IIS7 hosted on an internal network (publicly accessible) with a dedicated IP `1.2.3.4` where the root subdomain `dept.company.com` is linked (assigned by my company). We have an application server with a dedicated IP `5.6.7.8` hosted on an external server (cloud service) running Nginx as a reverse proxy.

**Problem**

I'm trying to redirect all requests from `dept.company.com/app-1` to the application server to each corresponding app.

Here's the rule on IIS

```
<rule name="RewriteAppToNginx" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^app/(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="dept.company.com" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://5.6.7.8/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

and here's the corresponding Nginx server block, where I have a sample `html` file placed just to check if it redirects properly.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/dept.company.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name dept.company.com;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Using these settings I'm able to get to the "Welcome to nginx!" page but not the specific server block where I have a sample html placed. Any help here would be great!

Comment: why not use nginx directly?

Answer (score 0):

A very common mistake by IIS beginners, and you missed `preserveHostHeader` as it is `false` by default,

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <proxy enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Without that, the upstream nginx didn't receive a valid Host header in requests to match `server_name dept.company.com;`, so you landed on the default site/page.

> Interestingly if you use nginx in front of IIS, the default is just the opposite that nginx preserves the original Host header.

### Reference

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59#mistake-3-write-proxy-rules-without-arr-proxy

Comment: Thank you @lex-li this works, I'm now trying to expose an app on port 3002 (nginx)
```location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002/;

       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_read_timeout 600s;

       proxy_redirect    off;
       proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;
       proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}```

Comment: I've used the code block above for requests within the nginx server but how do I modify that to accept requests routed from the IIS rewrite? Any help would be great. Also, great blog! Thanks for the write up!

Comment: @AmruthKiran that should be a separate question.